# Docusign | How to enable SBS in developer sandbox?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to test Express, AES and QES in docusign SandBox.

I'm not able to see the signature type options in my sandbox. I've seen in a documentation that there is way to choose the signature type.

I've further found that the SBS feature is not a default for Sandbox and need to get enabled by some Technical Contact.

Need help to know where should i request at docusign to get it done ?

PS: I just have a developer sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to first talk with your DocuSign representative. Setting up QES, in particular, is a discussion item. Eg how will the signers obtain their QES certs? Do they already have them? In what format?

If you want Express digital signatures enabled for your developer account, send your request and your demo account id to go-live@docusign.com

Comment: Thanks @Larry. I've raise an access request at go-live@docusign.com. Also, i don't have  DocuSign representative assigned to me and don't know what would be the procedure to get one.